# Catch Exception from running Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to catch an exception from a running thread and handle it in the calling thread. How would I to that the best way?

```
try {
  Runnable connect = new Runnable() {
    public synchronized void  run() {
      try {
        ... some code requiring long time
      } catch(Exception e) {
        ..I want to catch here and send to calling thread
      }
    }
  }

  synchronized(connect) {
    new Thread(connect).start();
    connect.wait();
    ...if exception then handle it
    ...keep on with code if no exception occurred
  }

} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use concurrency related classes and Future.http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best was is to not use Thread directly, but instead use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).  you can run a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) via a Thread if you desire, or get a Future by submitting a Callable to an Executor (the preferred method).  the Future gives you a convenient way to wait for the task to complete and to deal with the results (regular or exceptional).